# How to make a nav bar from Photoshop responsive?

Tags: html

Ok so I created a nav bar from Photoshop and i sliced up the parts. Then saved for web as images and html..

So it loaded up on Dreamweaver but when I launched the webpage, i have to scroll to the right to see the whole nav bar. I don't want this to happen. I wanna make it only take up 100% of the width, no more.
Here's the code i have so far:

```
    <link href="Stylsheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="csss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sketch</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Sketch.psd) -->

<table id="Table_01" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <a href="www.google.com"><img src="images/Sketch_01.gif" width="261" height="2000" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Sketch_02.gif" width="1" height="91" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Sketch_03.gif" width="250" height="2000" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Sketch_04.gif" width="1" height="92" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Sketch_05.gif" width="250" height="2000" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Sketch_06.gif" width="1" height="92" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Sketch_07.gif" width="1023" height="2000" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Sketch_08.png" width="1" height="92" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Sketch_09.gif" width="132" height="2000" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="91" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Sketch_10.gif" width="1" height="1909" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Sketch_11.gif" width="1" height="1908" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Sketch_12.gif" width="1" height="1908" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Sketch_13.gif" width="1" height="1908" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1908" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh man, Don't use Tables, just do it all in CSS.

Comment: i can make awesome nav bars with ps tho :3

Comment: Tables are meant for tabular data, CSS has all the position and formatting that you need to create a nav bar using images cut up from Photoshop with a fraction of the complexity.

Comment: solved, all i needed to do was add a nav div and put the stuff in there ;p

Comment: Try my answer, much simpler to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into using CSS as that it is much more suitable for image formatting and layout.

In the below example you can use CSS to set the `background-image` and the `left` and `top` parameters to move the slice div some number of pixels relative to the top left edge of the header div.

This can be easily modified to suit your needs, for example move the `height` and `width` from the `#header > div` (meaning div children of the #header) to each individual slice div.

Additionally, in this example the header is horizontally centered in the output, you can easily position the output to your desired location as well.

This is much more maintainable than using tables at that.

```css
/* CSS FILE */
/* Header Centered in window */

#header {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}
/* Make all header sections the same  */

#header > div {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.section1 {
  background-color: #F00;
  /* <- color for example */
  /* background-image:url(images/Slices_01.png); */ /* <- Use an image */
}
.section2 {
  left: 100px;
  background-color: #0F0;
}
.section3 {
  left: 200px;
  background-color: #00F;
}
.section4 {
  left: 300px;
  background-color: #F0F;
}
.section5 {
  left: 400px;
  background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Header Test</title>
  <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="section1"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section3"></div>
    <div class="section4"></div>
    <div class="section5"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```